# Evaluating an infinite series containing Digamma Function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, digamma-function

I was evaluating the integral  $$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2
 x\ln(1-x)}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$

I tried to use the series
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$
and interchanged the sum and the integral.
$$\mathcal{I}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\overbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\cdot \ln^2 x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx}^{\mathcal{J}}$$
Now, it's quite obvious that
$$\mathcal{J}=\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dn^2}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$
Now, I found in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003535/730361) by @[Olivier Oloa](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118798/olivier-oloa) that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^m}{1+x^n}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2n}\psi\bigg(\frac{m+n+1}{2n}\bigg)-\frac{1}{2n}\psi\bigg(\frac{m+1}{2n}\bigg)$$.
So,
\begin{align}\mathcal{J}&=\frac{\mathrm d^2}{dn^2}\bigg[\frac{1}{4}\psi\bigg(\frac{n+3}{4}\bigg)-\frac{1}{4}\psi\bigg(\frac{n+1}{4}\bigg)\bigg]\\&=\frac{1}{64}\bigg(\psi^{(2)}\bigg(\frac{n+3}{4}\bigg)-\psi^{(2)}\bigg(\frac{n+1}{4}\bigg)\bigg)\end{align}
So, the integral converts to the scary-looking series
$$\boxed{\mathcal{I}=\frac{-1}{64}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\bigg(\psi^{(2)}\bigg(\frac{n+3}{4}\bigg)-\psi^{(2)}\bigg(\frac{n+1}{4}\bigg)\bigg)}$$
Can someone hint on how to evaluate this infinite series? **I want a solution that is based on this approach that I gave.**

Comment: I don't think that converting this into a series is a good idea. I might post a solution.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, you may find ways to go [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773829/evaluating-int-01-frac-ln-2-leftx-right-ln-left1-x-right1x2-dx?noredirect=1), I suggest you make use of [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: @JorgeLayja This is the first time that Approachzero couldn't find that this is already asked. Anyways, thank you. I will, therefore, close this question.

Comment: I still suggest you remove this question so to prevent repeated questions flooding this site, you can post any alternative solution you come up with there.

Comment: I want an answer based on my approach.

Comment: @JorgeLayja This solution is not complete. I still want some hints from you on how to evaluate this series.

Comment: If a step in my attempt is wrong, you can always leave a comment.

Comment: With Mathematica and `MZIntegrate` packages I have: $$\frac{\pi ^2 C}{3}-\frac{\zeta \left(4,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{64}+\frac{\zeta \left(4,\frac{3}{4}\right)}{64}+\frac{1}{32}
   \pi ^3 \ln (2)\approx -0.27075$$ where $C$ is Catalan const.

Comment: It is hard to fix the question in the OP. We have an integral $\mathcal I$, which can be computed almost algorithmically, but instead of doing this we complicate maximally the computation of that integral, the digamma function $\psi$ appears, and in a final formula we have expressed $\mathcal I$ as a **series** involving terms which involve the **second derivative** of $\psi$ computed in rational, non-integral points. In bold face we have an **imperative request**.  If a potential answerer is not allowed to go back to the definition of $\mathcal I$, which formula for $\psi''$ should be used?