# why does $\pi$ always show up in $\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^c}{1+x^k} dx$ if $c\neq mk-1$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation

when I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796319/how-to-evaluate-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k4k3) I was interested in the sum $ \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3}$ but when I thought about the generalised sum $ \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{kn+c +1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N} -\{ 1 \}  , c  \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0  \}  $
I want to know what values of $k,c$ make $\pi $ show up in as a result of this infinite sum.

It is convenient to turn the sum into integrals
$$ \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{kn+c +1} = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \int_0 ^1  (-1)^n x^{kn+c}dx  = \int_0 ^1 \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{kn+c}dx  = \int_0 ^1 x^c\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{kn}dx = \int \frac{x^c}{1+x^k} dx$$

---

---

***I noticed the following pattern***

for *k=2*
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\color{red}{\int_0 ^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{\ln2}{2}}$$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx =1- \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\color{red}{\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^3}{1+x}dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\ln2}{2} }$$

---

for $k=3$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx =\frac{1}{18} (2\sqrt{3}\pi +\ln(64))$$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x}{1+x^3}dx = \frac{1}{18} (2\sqrt{3}\pi -\ln(8))$$
$$\color{red}{\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^3}dx =\frac{\ln2}{3}}$$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^3}{1+x^3}dx =1- (\frac{1}{9} (\sqrt{3}\pi +\ln(8)))$$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^4}{1+x^3}dx =\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{18} (-2\sqrt{3}\pi +\ln(64))$$
$$\color{red}{\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^5}{1+x^3}dx =\frac{1}{3} (1- \ln(2))}$$

---

it seems that $\pi$ must show up in every case where $c \neq mk-1$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ put I couldn't prove why.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{x^{k+c}}{1+x^k}=\frac{x^c+x^{k+c}}{1+x^k}-\frac{x^c}{1+x^k}=x^c-\frac{x^c}{1+x^k}$$Since $\int_0^1x^c\,dx$ does not involve $\pi$,  $\pi$ shows up in the integral  for $k$ if and only if it shows up for $k\pmod c$, so you only need to check $0\le k\le c-1$ to prove your hypothesis. Clearly if the $k=c-1$ case does not involve $\pi$ because the indefinite integral is simply one logarithm. I suspect that for $0\le k\le c-2$ you will need to split the integrand into partial fractions which require an $\arctan$, which is where the $\pi$ would come from.

Comment: The $\pi$ Term if there is then is given by :
$$\frac{\pi}{2k}\left(\cot\left(\frac{c+1}{2k}\pi\right)-\cot\left(\frac{c+1}{k}\pi\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ar familiar with the digamma function
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^c}{1+x^k} dx=\frac 1{2k}\left(\psi \left(\frac{c+k+1}{2 k}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{c+1}{2 k}\right)\right)$$ which, as you did, reduce to generalized harmonic numbers since
$$\psi(p)=H_{p-1}- \gamma$$

If $c=(m k-1)$
$$\int_0 ^1 \frac{x^c}{1+x^k} dx=\frac 1{2k}\left(\psi \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\right)$$

$$\psi \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{m}{2}\right)= (-1)^{m+1}\, 2\log (2)+a_m$$ where the first $a_m$ are
$$\left\{0,2,-1,\frac{5}{3},-\frac{7}{6},\frac{47}{30},-\frac{37}{30},
   \frac{319}{210},-\frac{533}{420},\frac{1879}{1260},-\frac{1627}{1
   260},\frac{20417}{13860}\right\}$$

For the coefficient of $\pi$ in the most general case, use what @Miracle Invoker gave in comments.

Comment: is there is other ways to do this without digamma function ?

Comment: @pie. Harmonic numbers but .... they are the same

Answer (score 1):

**By the reflection property of Beta function**

Letting $y=x^k$ transforms the integral into a Beta function as
$$
I=\frac{1}{k} \int_0^1 \frac{y^{\frac{c+1}{k}-1}}{1+y} d y
$$
So if $c \neq m k-1, \forall m \in N$, then $ \frac{c+1}{k} \in \mathbb{N}.$ By the reflection property of Beta function, we have $$
B(x, 1-x)=\pi \csc (\pi x) \quad \textrm{  for all }x \notin \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Hence $$
I=\frac{\pi}{k} \csc \frac{(k+1) \pi}{k}
$$
which explains why $\pi$ always appears in the the integral if $c \neq m k-1, \forall m \in N$.